# Difference Between Video Frame and Image File For Digital Image Processing

Tags: image-processing

In a article (Evaluation of Background Subtraction Techniques for Video Surveillance,S.Brutzer/B.Höferlin,G. Heidemann),type of frame is counted as a challenge.Is there any difference between frames  which comes from a video or a standard .bmp file for image processing???

Adem Metin ÇALI

Answer (score 0):

Generally an image is an image wherever it came from.
There might be differences in the image processing because of artifacts from the video - video files are often compressed in ways that changes the details of the picture.

The word "frame" has some more technical meanings in a video stream, especially one where each image is calculated from differences between previous and next frames - but you can think of frame and image as the same.